# Can I ask for a user's email address on my website, and automatically insert it to an email registration box on a different website that is not mine?

Tags: javascript

For example- asking a user's mail address on my own website, than automatically inserting it on the Facebook's registration page and showing the user the next Facebook page that will appear (if hypothetically Facebook required email only for registration).

Thanks!

Comment: i don't if its possible. Since the control is passed to the other website, it can done if the other website(eg;facebook) allows to do so.

Comment: no..until the website is XSS vulnerable :P